# Internal Server Error due to `import` in Python

Tags: python, json, apache, server, cgi

So this is really weird, and I don't know if I'm overlooking something silly, or if there's something here:

I'm running a CGI script on my university's Apache server, here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import csv
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: application/json"
print
print "Hello World!"

file = open("test.csv", "a")
writer = csv.writer(file)

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
for key in fs.keys():
    # print "%s = %s" % (key, fs[key].value)
    writer.writerow((key, fs[key].value))
```

The purpose of the script is that I can access it with a URL like this:

`http://sample.com/run.cgi?param=one&param=two`

And the script will write the data to a CSV file on the server. This works perfectly.

The problem is that I want to send data to the server from JavaScript/Python code, in JSON format, or as a JSON string to be parsed by the Python script on the server. In order to do this, I need to add `import json` to the Python script, right?

This is where it all goes wrong - if I don't add `import json` - it all works, and I can access the URL through my browser, and it will write the file on the server. However, once I add `import json`, access to the script from the browser doesn't work - I get the *"500 Internal Server Error"*. You would think that there's a problem with the import, but running the CGI script on the server side works perfectly... the only thing that stops working is activating the script from remote URL / code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check server's error logs. Since the server is maintained by your university, you can contact the person-in-charge for the same.

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92 I tried contacting them, but bureaucracy being as it is, I hope someone here could offer things to try..

Comment: The issue could be as simple unavailability of module on the server.

Comment: But the script runs fine when I run it locally on the server (through SSH). Only remotely running the script is a problem (i.e. via URL or remote Python code).